# Keep dash favorites in Applications Grid?

Tags: gnome

Whenever I add an app to my favorites, the app goes missing from the applications grid.

I prefer my favorites to still show up in the grid. Is there a way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the [Favourites in AppGrid](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4485/favourites-in-appgrid/) extension, works great.

Comment: Thank you so much!